# I have sdk. Is ndk neccesarry for eclipse

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I have eclipse Kepler and I am having "Android-Sdk-Windows" files. But I cannot able to make an android project in eclipse.. Do i need NDK necessary.

### I already have experience with opening project with just "sdk" and eclipse.. But this times How can i enter the "sdk" path instead of "ndk".

Or Teach me what is "sdk" and "ndk"

```
i tried eclipse->preference->android-> But i can only see NDK location.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839218/android-ndk-vs-sdk-if-features-are-concerned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native methods are platform-specific code. They are usually written in languages such as C or C++ and contained in libraries(dll's). It is possible to create a hybrid Java application that benefits from such libraries.

**Reasons for Using Native Methods**

1. Gaining access to special capabilities of your device or or Android
   OS
2. Gaining extra speed
3. Gaining access to a large body of existing legacy code

Typically, good use cases for the NDK are CPU-intensive applications such as game engines, signal processing, and physics simulation

The **major disadvantage** of native methods is that you won't have **cross-platform capability**.

**What is Android NDK**

> The **Android NDK** is a companion tool to the Android SDK that lets
>   you build performance-critical portions of your apps in native code.
>   It provides headers and libraries that allow you to build activities,
>   handle user input, use hardware sensors, access application resources,
>   and more, when programming in C or C++. If you write native code, your
>   applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run
>   inside of a virtual machine on the device. The fundamental Android
>   application model does not change.

Now if you don't know what native code is, then probably you don't need to use native code. Android NDK documentation explains this well:

> ..., you should understand that the NDK will not benefit most apps. As
>   a developer, you need to balance its benefits against its drawbacks.
>   Notably, using native code on Android generally does not result in a
>   noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app
>   complexity. In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential
>   to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++. When
>   examining whether or not you should develop in native code, think
>   about your requirements and see if the Android framework APIs provide
>   the functionality that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need the ndk, in order to build an android project. If you are having difficulties with eclipse, I would suggest using Android Studio unless you are dead set on eclipse. I use both, and strongly prefer to use Android Studio whenever I can.

If you decide to stay with eclipse, it is as easy as downloading the ADT plugin by putting the url in the input box under Help->Install New Software, launching and downloading the sdk from the  Android sdk manager, restarting eclipse, and then starting a new Android project. Hopefully you do not have to do anything to configure java or anything else.

The ndk is a way of accessing things from a lower level, in order to bypass certain things, or squeeze more performance out of a phone for highly intense operations, or finally to be able to port c/c++ code from different project. i.e. You can write a Opengl ES game in c and reuse most the code for web, ios, and android this way. But that goes beyond the scope of the question, and this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should ensure you have installed ADT plugin .