# Difference between SDK and NDK in android

Tags: android, c++, sdk, android-ndk

Since 2 Years I am working as Android Application Developer. I generally use android SDK for all the Android Apps Development. Now I have a project which is an Android App in which I have to use SDK as well as NDK for App development (As per Client requirement). 
But as I don't have any experience with NDK I don't know what is it. In some Blogs I have read that NDK development is based on c++.

**Is it true that to work with NDK one must have the complete knowledge of c++ ?**

Please Help !!

Comment: have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839218/android-ndk-vs-sdk-if-features-are-concerned) may be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of NDK means you have to write portion of code in C/C++ just to achieve the speed. If it is client requirement then you have no option. But keep in mind that you should use NDK only when you feel you need better performance. And of course you must have some understanding of c/c++ to use NDK.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Mostly I'm using NDK when I'm dealing with ImageEditing app.

Comment: You can also use OpenCV for image editing in android. I think you need not use NDK for that.

Comment: Yes, OpenCV is the best option to start with when we are dealing with ImageEditing app. So, in my project I have initially used OpenCV & later to improve the application performance I used NDK. Combination of both into a single project was the most challenging part of my project.

Answer (score 1):

- NDK

1. NDK is a set of tools to compile C code to shared lib,
   which you could use in your app - and that's all.
2. Enables legacy code re-use between iOS and Android platforms
   Good for implementing CPU intensive operations that don't
   allocate much memory like signal processing, physics simulations.

- SDK

1. SDK is the main development kit for Android apps - it contains tools for Java and resources (png, xml) compiling, packaging to apk file, installing, running and debugging them on a device, an emulator, documentation, etc.
2. Java has superior memory management model Superior threading model Better exception handling model Rich set of libraries Superior support for unicode characters.